# Get bools out of byte and the other way

Tags: math, casting, binary, types

Simple question:

How do i tell which bits in the byte are set to 0 and which are set to 1

for example:

```
//That code would obviously wont work, but how do i make something similar that would work?
byte myByte = 0X32;

foreach(bool bit in myByte)
{
  Console.WriteLine(bit);
}


//Part 2 revert
bool[] bits = new bool[8];
bits[0] = 0
bits[1] = 0
bits[2] = 0
bits[3] = 0
bits[4] = 0
bits[5] = 1
bits[6] = 0
bits[7] = 0

byte newByte = (byte)bits;
```

The entier internet is full of examples, but i just cant figure out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wanna use bit operations

```
k = bits = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 256; i <<= 1)
  bool[k++] = (bits & i) != 0;


k = bits = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 256; i <<= 1)
  if (bool[k++]) bits |= i;
```

Answer (score 1):

`BitArray` class will be the simplest (though not necessarily the fastest) way possible.

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to use this class, for example:

byte myByte = 0X32;
BitArray byt = new BitArray(myByte);

foreach (bool bit in byt)
{
    Console.WriteLine(bit.ToString());
}
 

but then im getting 32 0's instead of 8. im doing something wrong, just no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

You can AND them.  If the 1 bit is set in both numbers it will remain set.  I'm not sure exactly what that sample is after, but AND'ing a bit with 1 will give you a true(1) or false(0).

0010 & 1010 = 0010